# Getting last index of arraylist with condition

Tags: java, arraylist, equals, contains, lastindexof

I have list as shown below, as this includes many repeated field values of AbcConSch

```
List<AbcConSch> asBeanList= tbCondition.getAbcConScheds();
AbcConSch abcSchedule = asBeanList.get(i);
```

this list has bag which has elements of data, so i need to get lastindexof() asBeanList with condition of field value="ConditionCode".

i have tried with below code to get value

```
i == asBeanList.lastIndexOf(abcSchedule.getSrConditionCode().contains(SC_CONDITION_CODE_ABC))
```

Thanks for helping and support in advance.
Arun

Answer (score 3):

You can implement your own `lastIndexOf()` method, and let it take an expression to match:

```
public static <E> int lastIndexOf(List<E> list, Predicate<E> predicate) {
    for (ListIterator<E> iter = list.listIterator(list.size()); iter.hasPrevious(); )
        if (predicate.test(iter.previous()))
            return iter.nextIndex();
    return -1;
}
```

*Test*

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("AA", "BB", "ABC", "CC");
System.out.println(lastIndexOf(list, s -> s.contains("AA")));
System.out.println(lastIndexOf(list, s -> s.contains("A")));
System.out.println(lastIndexOf(list, s -> s.contains("BB")));
System.out.println(lastIndexOf(list, s -> s.contains("B")));
System.out.println(lastIndexOf(list, s -> s.contains("CC")));
System.out.println(lastIndexOf(list, s -> s.contains("C")));
System.out.println(lastIndexOf(list, s -> s.contains("DD")));
```

*Output*

```
0
2
1
2
3
3
-1
```

For your code, you'd use it like this:

```
List<AbcConSch> asBeanList = tbCondition.getAbcConScheds();
int i = lastIndexOf(asBeanList, a -> a.getSrConditionCode().contains(SC_CONDITION_CODE_ABC));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use this way.

```
privat ArrayList<AbcConch>abc=new ArrayList();
List<AbcConSch> asBeanList= tbCondition.getAbcConScheds();
 for (int i=0;i<=asBeanList.size();i++{
  if(asBeanList.get(i).getSrConditionCode().contains(SC_CONDITION_CODE_ABC)){
  abc.add(asBeanList.get(i);
 }
}
```

and last you can get last index value

```
int i = abc.size()
```

Comment: Thank you very much.. it has fulfilled my question.

Comment: please consider it upvote and accept it, so it help other as well.

Answer (score -1):

The following is the code for the Java language function `List.lastIndexOf()`:

```
public int lastIndexOf(Object o) {
        if (o == null) {
            for (int i = size-1; i >= 0; i--)
                if (elementData[i]==null)
                    return i;
        } else {
            for (int i = size-1; i >= 0; i--)
                if (o.equals(elementData[i]))
                    return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

From here, you can trivially modify it to accept an arbitrary function:

```
public int lastIndexOf(Object o) {

    // delete null checks (or leave in if your code requires them)

        for (int i = size-1; i >= 0; i--)
            if (yourCustomConditionHere)  // add your custom condition
                return i;

    }
```